# Poor phrasing in probability problem, what is the problem even asking for?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> If $m$ things are distributed among $a$ men and $b$ women, show that the chance that the number of things received by man is$${1\over2} {{(b + a)^m - (b - a)^m}\over{(b+a)^m}}.$$

I'm not asking for a solution with this problem (or even help with the substantial content), but instead, what is this question even asking for? The phrasing is bad since the textbook is not written by a native English speaker.

---

As an update I figured it out. It's showing that the chance the number of things received by man is **odd**.

Comment: There does seem to be something missing from the statement.  The final answer is to be a probability (or "chance" as the problem has it) but we aren't told what event we are to consider.  Do you have a link to the problem?  Maybe we can reverse engineer what the question was.

Comment: Hi @lulu I figured out, check out the edit.

Comment: Looks possible.  Certainly works for $m=1$.  Induction should finish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Big hint**

The number of things received by men has a binomial distribution, with $m$ trials and probability $p=a/(a+b)$. The probability of getting an odd number of gifts is found by summing the binomial probability over all odd numbers:
$$
P(\text{men get odd # things})=\binom{m}{1}p^1 (1-p)^{m-1}+\binom m3p^3(1-p)^{m-3}+\binom m5 p^5(1-p)^{m-5}+\dots
$$
The question is, why does this summation simply to $\frac12[\color{blue}{(b+a)^m}-\color{red}{(b-a)^m}]/(b+a)^m$? To answer this, let us expand the two binomial powers in the numberator using the binomial theorem:
\begin{align}
\color{blue}{(b+a)^m} &= \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}k b^ka^{m-k}    \\
\color{red }{(b-a)^m} &= \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}k (-1)^{m-k}b^ka^{m-k}
\end{align}
When you subtract these two expressions, you will find that all of the terms for which $k$ is even will cancel out, while the odd $k$ terms will remain. Write out both expressions fully for $m=6$, and subtract them, to see what I mean if it is not clear. This observation about only odd terms remaining allows you to quickly prove that $\frac12[\color{blue}{(b+a)^m}-\color{red}{(b-a)^m}]/(b+a)^m$ is equal to the first expression for $P(\text{men get odd # things})$ I gave.